# ArcGIS Pro/Online: deleting a field "General function failure[Incorrect syntax near ','. Incorrect syntax near','.]"

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro I accidentally deleted two fields by clicking the "Delete Field" button at the top of the attribute table. The two fields were "GlobalID" and "Appointment".  I was trying to delete selected features at the time. Now I can't edit or delete any features in this layer. I get an error message of: "Update table row. Failed to "Update table row". General function failure[Incorrect syntax near ','. Incorrect syntax near','.]".  If I click on one of the features in the Map window the deleted fields still appear, but instead of having information about them they just say the field name again. Preferably I could restore these fields and go back to where I was previously. Otherwise, how do I push this delete through to the individual features. "GlobalID" has no bearing on my workflow, and "Appointment" will only affect a few features at this point.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just logged a bug on this "feature". The Delete Field and Delete Selected icons are very similar, and even an experienced user will push the wrong one. When you selected "some" records and accidentally hit the "Delete Field" button, you in fact just truncated your entire feature class (deleted everything). There is no recovery. In addition, GlobalID, once enabled on a feature class, is not deletable. You will have to export your (un-deleted) data to a new feature class with no GlobalID defined if you truly do not want it.